# Update accounts.name when accounts.id is modified

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a database where in the accounts table the "username" is the "id".

Now I need to add to the table the field "name" which will work as the "id", so if I create a new account, I need the "id" field to also copy it's value at "name" field.

There's any way to automate that without modifying the account creation process? So "name" will always copy the "id" value.

I'm running PhpMyAdmin in Windows (MySQL).

I need this because I have to work with 2 apps in the same database and I don't have the code neither can get any updates. One of them is using "id" field to verify users "usernames" and the other one is using the "name" field to verify users.

I know this is not a good thing, I didn't develop it. But the only thing I can do is modify the database.

Comment: MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQL-Server, SQLite, etc, etc?

Comment: Please provide sample data and your desired results.  It is not obvious what you are doing.

Comment: MySQL sorry I forgot that detail

Comment: This is not good database design. If you have a field "id", you should not automatically add a second field "name" that has exactly the same value. This does not make any sense. Or please explain why you need the field "id" and field "name" have the same values. If it's just the name of the column in a select query, you could try: "select id as name from accounts".

Comment: Added explanation why I need this design, I know it sounds weird

Comment: If I change the name of the field, one of the softwares will stop work, it's not possible to add an alias? like for commands and dns you can put an alias without loosing the original name

Answer (score 1):

Use a trigger on insert

CREATE TRIGGER insert_name AFTER INSERT ON accounts
   FOR EACH ROW SET name = NEW.id

Of course if the id column can be updated you will also need an update trigger

Comment: Please @Joakim can you explain a bit what that trigger is doing? I'm really newbie at databases

Comment: When you insert a new row into the table the trigger will set `name` to the value for `id` for the new row

Answer (score 0):

You can do it before storing it in the Database.
Free advice:
You have to change the design of the Database because it will produce anomalies.